# SSHJ host fingerprint verification with multiple keys

Tags: ssh, sshj

We are connecting via ssh to a remote host from java with the sshj library. To do so we have configured a single fingerprint that is used during host verification.

After some time we started to get random host key verification errors. Out of multiple ssh connections, only some fails with

```
Disconnecting because none of the configured Host key verifiers ([net.schmizz.sshj.transport.verification.FingerprintVerifier$1@1696cbbf]) could verify 'ssh-ed25519' host key with fingerprint ... for ...
```

As far as I understand this is because the host has multiple keys configured for different algorithms (`ssh-rsa`, `ssh-ed25519`, `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`).

1. What is the correct approach here, should we add multiple verifiers, one for each known key?
2. Why is it random? What method is used by ssh/sshj to select the key being used?

Comment: Connecting to remote host - Are you connecting directly to the host or port forwarding involved ?

Comment: No forwarding I know of but the infrastructure is managed by a separate team. Is there an easy way to find out?

Comment: I will check but you have an insecure option though i.e by setting the stricthostkeychecking=no for ssh.

Comment: There might be a distributed SSH farm behind and each of them returns a different host key? Some of the times the connection is routed to a server from which you don't have the "correct" key.